# Bash: grepped string fed to regex produces unexpected result

Tags: linux, bash, regex, grep

I'm a bit befuddled, but this bit of script is producing unexpected results.
I'm getting that htmlstring is

```
<!-- <td><a href="https://aeronav.faa.gov/upload_313-d/terminal/DDTPPA_190228.zip"</a>DDTPPA_190228</td> -->
```

but then the regex is getting '1901' as the cycle which should be impossible based on the initial value of htmlstring. W.T.F....

The values of htmlstring and cycle will change as time passes, but are valid for the next month or so.

```
if [ ! -e /tmp/dtpp ]
then
    curl https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/ -o /tmp/dtpp
fi
htmlstring=`grep "DDTPPA" /tmp/dtpp | grep zip |  head -n 2 `
echo $htmlstring
 regex='DDTPPA_([0-9]{4})[0-9]{2}'
[[ $htmlstring =~ $regex ]]
cycle=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo "cycle:"
echo $cycle
extractCycle $htmlstring
```

I'm running GNU bash, version 5.0.0(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu),
grep (GNU grep) 3.3,
head (GNU coreutils) 8.30.

Comment: The output I'm getting for `grep "DDTPPA" /tmp/dtpp|grep zip|head -n2` is in two lines. The regex matches the first occurrence, if you want the last occurrence try with regex `.*DDTPPA_([0-9]{4})[0-9]{2}`

Comment: Use `echo "$var"` instead of `echo $var`. Without the double-quotes, the shell does word-splitting (and wildcard expansion) on them, which can cause confusion. In this case, it's turning two lines of data into one long line of output. Well, it would, except that the output from `curl` includes a carriage return at the end of each line, which causes the second line of data to be printed *on top of* the first, effectively erasing the first line and confusing matters completely. So you're seeing the second line, but (as @Paulo said) you're looking at the regex match from the first line.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson Yes, I thought that, but surprisingly the double quotes in this case don't matter, with or without double quotes the result is the same (and bash doesn't print error messages).

Comment: @Paulo You're right that the lack of double-quotes isn't affecting the result, but it is what's making it hard to tell what's going on.